# Storage Size of addrinfo isn't known

Tags: c, networking

I am writing a simple network program in C. When I turned on `-Wall` with `--std=c11`, I got an error message about the way am declaring a struct.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>


int main() {

        struct addrinfo res;

    return 0;
}
```

The type `addrinfo` is defined in the sys/types.h file. I don't get an error when using a pointer.

How can I resolve this error message?

```
simple.c:9:25: error: storage size of ‘res’ isn’t known
         struct addrinfo res;
                         ^
```

Comment: `man 2 bind`: *The  actual  structure  passed  for  the  addr  argument will depend on the address family.  The sockaddr structure is defined as something like:
           struct sockaddr {
               sa_family_t sa_family;
               char        sa_data[14];
           }
The only purpose of this structure is to cast the structure pointer  passed in addr in order to avoid compiler warnings.* You don't create an object of type `struct sockaddr` for normal use, you create an objcect of the appropriate subtype, `struct sockaddr_in` for ipv4, for example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Several points:

1. The type `addrinfo` is actually defined in `netdb.h`.
2. You can use the `-E` flag to `gcc` to see the pre-processor output and discover that the `addrinfo` structure is actually not defined in your code. Now you should suspect that probably some definition is missing.
3. As can be seen [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html), in order to expose the definition you need to use the `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` [feature test macro](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).
4. So, this should resolve the mentioned error message:

   ```
   #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L

   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/socket.h>
   #include <netdb.h>

   int main() {
       struct addrinfo res;

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. -E looks really useful

Comment: Glad I could help :-).