# Compiler error in showip.c from Beej's Guide to Network Programming book (section 5.1)

Tags: c, network-programming

I am trying to learn network programming from [Beej's](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/split/system-calls-or-bust.html#getaddrinfoprepare-to-launch) book on network programming. There is a piece of code in section 5.1

```
/*
** showip.c -- show IP addresses for a host given on the command line
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    int status;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: showip hostname\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // AF_INET or AF_INET6 to force version
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 2;
    }

    printf("IP addresses for %s:\n\n", argv[1]);

    for(p = res;p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        void *addr;
        char *ipver;

        // get the pointer to the address itself,
        // different fields in IPv4 and IPv6:
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
            ipver = "IPv4";
        } else { // IPv6
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
            ipver = "IPv6";
        }

        // convert the IP to a string and print it:
        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
        printf("  %s: %s\n", ipver, ipstr);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res); // free the linked list

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this inside Ubuntu terminal, I get the following error

```
showip.c: In function ‘main’:
showip.c:15:25: error: storage size of ‘hints’ isn’t known
   15 |         struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
      |                         ^~~~~
showip.c:28:23: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getaddrinfo’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   28 |         if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
showip.c:29:54: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gai_strerror’; did you mean ‘strerror’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   29 |                 fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                      strerror
showip.c:29:48: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   29 |                 fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
      |                                               ~^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                |     |
      |                                                |     int
      |                                                char *
      |                                               %d
showip.c:35:37: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct addrinfo’
   35 |         for(p = res;p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
      |                                     ^~
showip.c:41:22: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct addrinfo’
   41 |                 if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
      |                      ^~
showip.c:42:75: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct addrinfo’
   42 |                         struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
      |                                                                           ^~
showip.c:46:77: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct addrinfo’
   46 |                         struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
      |                                                                             ^~
showip.c:52:28: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct addrinfo’
   52 |                 inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
      |                            ^~
showip.c:56:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘freeaddrinfo’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   56 |         freeaddrinfo(res); // free the linked list
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I checked the [errata](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/errata.html) page given on his site and did not find it helpful. It seems that all required libraries are included here, so I don't see what could be the source of errors. If somebody can point it out, that would be nice.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storage Size of addrinfo isn't known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541985/storage-size-of-addrinfo-isnt-known)

Comment: @stark yes, that does compile the code. But when I run `a.out  https://www.google.com/`  I get the error `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@stark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1216776/stark) mentioned, [Storage size of addrinfo isn't known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541985/storage-size-of-addrinfo-isnt-known) should help compile the code.

As I don't have enough reputation to comment, in regards to the runtime error `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`, you need to remove the protocol `https://` and the terminating forward slash.

If you look at the manpages for `getaddrinfo`:

```
node specifies either a
numerical network address (for IPv4, numbers-and-dots notation as
supported by inet_aton(3); for IPv6, hexadecimal string format as
supported by inet_pton(3)), or a network hostname
```

We only need the hostname and not the protocol. So you should run the program as follows:

```
$ ./a.out www.google.com
IP addresses for www.google.com:

  IPv4: 142.251.163.106
...
```

In fact if you look at the page you linked, it gives you sample outputs:

```
$ showip www.example.net
IP addresses for www.example.net:

  IPv4: 192.0.2.88

$ showip ipv6.example.com
IP addresses for ipv6.example.com:

  IPv4: 192.0.2.101
  IPv6: 2001:db8:8c00:22::171
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. Network programming is so hard.